# mysql error: exceeded the max connections per hour

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm getting an error while running php script for Wordpress site on same domain:

```
Could not connect: User 'abc' has exceeded the 'max_connections_per_hour' resource (current value: 10)
```

What should be the limit for MySql database? Now should I connect to the database?

Comment: Talk to your web host.

Comment: Ten per hour is really, really low.

Answer (score 6):

You exceed limit for mysql, take a look at mysql doc, and you can see this :

```
GRANT ALL ON customer.* TO 'francis'@'localhost'
IDENTIFIED BY 'frank'
WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 20
     MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 10
     MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 5;
```

You just have to increase MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR or to remove limit, just use this :

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'francis'@'localhost' WITH MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0;
```

To allow persistent connection on WordPress, take a look at this article (I have not tested it myself) : http://www.mydigitallife.info/using-php-mysql-persistent-connections-to-run-wordpress-blog/

Comment: what exactly it will do, will change limit to unlimited ? can it be dangerous ?

Comment: That is, assuming his web host hasn't set a limit, which he has no privilege to override.

Comment: ideally what should be the limit for MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR ?

Comment: Removing limit can be dangerous ! that true !

The best thing should be to add persistante connexion to prevent re-connexion

Comment: i have a website which gets around 90,000+ visitors...but its not running because of this for months....what should i change the MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR value to ? any solution ?

Comment: I edited my answer, follow the link and change the config file to allow persistent connexion

Comment: nice article, but it is giving the same error after changing to mysql_pconnect, im using a simple php script to check connection, but it is giving the same error, maybe anything at phpmyadmin side required ? should is change limit to 5000 ? or anything related to emptying cache ? database size ?

Comment: To check where the problem come from, start by setting max_connections_per_hour to 0 (unlimited). Your website will work fine, then try to play with mysql_pconnect

Comment: If you have that many users in your website opening requests I would advice you to look on how to implement a connection pool to your application. That way connections will be reused by the application and requests would be queued to use a connection whenever it gets released back to the pool